# Sending User Information to phpMyAdmin and Displaying it in App

Tags: java, android, sqlite, phpmyadmin

So in my application I have a user registration form. In this user registration form there is a field which asks for the home address of a user and I want to be able to send whatever address the user has entered into that field, into the columns I have created in my Db. I use `SQLiteHandler`. Some of the code was outsourced so in the code below there is functions that work but I don't know how and where to replicate it for this new field that I have added.

This is what I did and for some reason the app keeps crashing while trying to logging in to sign up a new user. I narrowed it down to the `SQLiteHandler.java` class because when I comment out the code I did it lets me use the rest of the app. In `LogCat` the Stack Trace says that there isn't a column in the table `user` named `patient_address` but there is.

***I am so sorry for posting so much code but I really don't know where to start or where to end. I appreciate any positive input from anyone who may have an idea of where to start!***

**SQLiteHandler Code:** [FULL CODE IS HERE](https://pastebin.com/S6JBbCYX)

Static Variables:

```
 // Login Table Columns names
 private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
 private static final String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fristname";
 private static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "lastname";
 private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
 private static final String KEY_RANK = "rank";
 private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
 private static final String KEY_HCP_ID = "HCP_id";
 private static final String KEY_ENCRYPTEDPASSWORD = "encrypted_password";
 private static final String KEY_SALT = "salt";
 private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
 private static final String KEY_TITLE = "tilte";
 private static final String KEY_HOSPITAL = "hospital";
 private static final String KEY_PROFESSION = "profession";
 private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER = "phone_number";
 private static final String KEY_PATIENT_NUMBER = "patient_number";
 private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "patient_address";
```

Creating the db OnCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_HOSPITAL + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PROFESSION + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_RANK + " INT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," 
            + KEY_UID + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_PASSWORD + "TEXT," 
            + KEY_ENCRYPTEDPASSWORD + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_SALT + "TEXT,"
            + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER + " INT," 
            + KEY_HCP_ID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PATIENT_NUMBER+ " TEXT," 
            + KEY_ADDRESS + "TEXT UNIQUE" 
            +")";
```

addUser void:

```
 public void addUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, user.getFirstname()); // FirstName
    values.put(KEY_LASTNAME, user.getLastname()); // LastName
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, user.getEmail()); // Email
    values.put(KEY_UID, user.getUnique_id()); // Email
    values.put(KEY_RANK, user.getRank()); // rank
    values.put(KEY_ENCRYPTEDPASSWORD, user.getEncrypted_password()); // Patient Of the HCP with this uid
    values.put(KEY_SALT, user.getSalt()); // Patient Of the HCP with this uid
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, user.getPassword()); // Password
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, user.getTitle()); // HCP name
    values.put(KEY_HOSPITAL, user.getHospital()); // HCP name
    values.put(KEY_PROFESSION, user.getProfession()); // HCP name
    values.put(KEY_HCP_ID, user.getHCP_id()); // Patient Of the HCP with this uid
    values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER, user.getPhone_number()); // phone number
    values.put(KEY_PATIENT_NUMBER, user.getPatient_number()); // patient number
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, user.getAddress()); // Patient Home Address

    // Inserting Row
    //long id = db.replace(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    long id = db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_USER, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

}
```

User getUserDetails():

```
public User getUsersDetails() {
    User user=new User();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.setFirstname(cursor.getString(1));
        user.setLastname(cursor.getString(2));
        user.setTitle(cursor.getString(3));
        user.setHospital(cursor.getString(4));
        user.setProfession(cursor.getString(5));
        user.setRank(Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(6)));
        user.setEmail(cursor.getString(7));
        user.setUnique_id(cursor.getString(8));
        user.setPassword(cursor.getString(9));
        user.setEncrypted_password(cursor.getString(10));
        user.setSalt(cursor.getString(11));
        user.setPhone_number(Long.valueOf(cursor.getString(12)));
        user.setHCP_id(cursor.getString(13));
        user.setPatient_number(cursor.getString(14));
        user.setAddress(cursor.getString(15));

    }
    else{
        user=null;
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user


    return user;
}
```

getUserDetailsByEmail:

```
 public User getUserDetailsByEmail(String email) {
     User user=new User();

     String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER + " WHERE "+ KEY_EMAIL + " = '"+ email+"'";
     Log.d("tables select", selectQuery);
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

     Log.d("tables",tableToString(db,TABLE_USER));

     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
     // Move to first row
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
         user.setFirstname(cursor.getString(1));
         user.setLastname(cursor.getString(2));
         user.setTitle(cursor.getString(3));
         user.setHospital(cursor.getString(4));
         user.setProfession(cursor.getString(5));
         user.setRank(Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(6)));
         user.setEmail(cursor.getString(7));
         user.setUnique_id(cursor.getString(8));
         user.setPassword(cursor.getString(9));
         user.setEncrypted_password(cursor.getString(10));
         user.setSalt(cursor.getString(11));
         user.setPhone_number(Long.valueOf(cursor.getString(12)));
         user.setHCP_id(cursor.getString(13));
         user.setPatient_number(cursor.getString(14));
         user.setAddress(cursor.getString(15));
     }else{
         user=null;
     }

     cursor.close();
     db.close();
     // return user



     return user;
 }
```

Getting the User's details by finding out who signed the up:

```
public ArrayList<User> getUsersDetailsByHCP_id(String HCP_id) {
     User user;

     String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER + " WHERE "+ KEY_HCP_ID + " = '"+ HCP_id+"'";
     Log.d("tables select", selectQuery);
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

     Log.d("tables",tableToString(db,TABLE_USER));

     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
     ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();

     // Move to first row
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     if (cursor.getCount() > 0) do {
         user = new User();
         user.setFirstname(cursor.getString(1));
         user.setLastname(cursor.getString(2));
         user.setTitle(cursor.getString(3));
         user.setHospital(cursor.getString(4));
         user.setProfession(cursor.getString(5));
         user.setRank(Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(6)));
         user.setEmail(cursor.getString(7));
         user.setUnique_id(cursor.getString(8));
         user.setPassword(cursor.getString(9));
         user.setEncrypted_password(cursor.getString(10));
         user.setSalt(cursor.getString(11));
         user.setPhone_number(Long.valueOf(cursor.getString(12)));
         user.setHCP_id(cursor.getString(13));
         user.setPatient_number(cursor.getString(14));
         user.setAddress(cursor.getString(15));
         list.add(user);
     } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     else{
        Log.i (TAG,"GetUsersDetailByHCP_id  no Users found");
     }


     cursor.close();
     db.close();
     // return user
     return list;
 }
```

**Stack track from LogCat:**

```
0:45:28.288 27837-27837/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) table user has no column named patient_address
11-09 10:45:28.293 27837-27837/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana, PID: 27837
                                               android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table user has no column named patient_address (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO user(encrypted_password,profession,password,fristname,patient_number,patient_address,hospital,HCP_id,tilte,rank,lastname,email,uid,salt,phone_number) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                                               #################################################################
                                               Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                               Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                (table user has no column named patient_address (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO user(encrypted_password,profession,password,fristname,patient_number,patient_address,hospital,HCP_id,tilte,rank,lastname,email,uid,salt,phone_number) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?))
                                               #################################################################
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1008)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:573)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1864)
                                                   at co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.helper.SQLiteHandler.addUser(SQLiteHandler.java:181)
                                                   at co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.activity.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:180)
                                                   at co.uk.mednet.mednet_ghana.activity.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:163)
                                                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
                                                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                                                   at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Database Structure:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT," + KEY_HOSPITAL + " TEXT,"+ KEY_PROFESSION + " TEXT,"+ KEY_RANK + " INT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_UID + " TEXT," + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT," + KEY_ENCRYPTEDPASSWORD + " TEXT," + KEY_SALT + " TEXT,"+ KEY_PHONE_NUMBER + " INT," + KEY_HCP_ID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PATIENT_NUMBER+ " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + "TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
```

Comment: your log says `table user has no column named patient_address`. are you sure that your database is created successfully?

Comment: `in my application I have a user registration form`. What kind of? Where does it come from? How do you display it? Dont know where you are talking about.

Comment: What does this have to do with phpadmin and mysql?

Comment: the database is in phpMyAdmin. I removed the `mysql` tag. The registration form is purely just a EditText and a TextView form. @MohammadJulfikar I have checked the database and the `patient_address` column is created successfully and I have referenced it properly too.

Comment: @DezG your logcat says `table user has no column named patient_address`. that means definitely problem with your sqlite. I provided a sample code. You can check

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is not a database: it is a way to *view* a database. This is not me being petty and pedantic: the difference is quite important. Can you show us the actual structure of your database (hint: it should include the phrase `CREATE TABLE`)?

Comment: @TRiG sorry. I have put [the structure of the database in a pastebin here](https://pastebin.com/1BUavG2M) and also its at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I am going provide my own working code.Later you can modify it.

```
public class EmployeeDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public EmployeeDB(Context context){
    super(context,ETBL_NAME,null,1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE "+ ETBL_NAME + "( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_ID + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_PROGRAMME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_MOBILE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_WORKING + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onCreate(db);
}
public boolean AddInfo(String name,String id,String programme,String email,String mobile,String working){
    boolean flag;

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME,name);
    values.put(COLUMN_ID,id);
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL,email);
    values.put(COLUMN_MOBILE,mobile);
    values.put(COLUMN_PROGRAMME,programme);
    values.put(COLUMN_WORKING,working);

    long result = database.insert(ETBL_NAME,null,values);

    flag = result != -1;

    return flag;
}

public boolean DeleteAll(){

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int affected = database.delete(ETBL_NAME,null,null);
    return affected > 0;

}

public Cursor GetAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + ETBL_NAME;
    return database.rawQuery(query,null);
}

public boolean updateDetails(String matri,String row, String content)
{
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(row, content);

    int i =  database.update(ETBL_NAME, args, COLUMN_ID + "='" + matri +"'", null);
    return i > 0;
}
}
```

What i assume from your code is, your database was not created successfully. May be you forgot to executeSQL in your oncreate method. Your insertion part seems good. You can follow my functions. All of them are working

Comment: But whats confusing is that it worked fine before I added in this new `patient_address` column

Comment: ow.. you should have told this earlier. in this case, you have to uninstall the app and install again.. otherwise sqlite will not be updated

Comment: I am using the Run function in android studio so the app automatically uninstalls. I still tried it and it still crashed

Comment: Do you want me to show you my Db so you can check if I have the column inserted correctly? Might need to message me on something else so I don't clutter this post

Comment: @DezG I was about to ask that. Can you just edit your question and share the full code?

Comment: I wouldn't be able too. StackOverflow says its too many characters over by like 22k. But I put it in a [paste bin](https://pastebin.com/S6JBbCYX)

Comment: how can you have two unique ID in one table? your email is already set to `UNIQUE` and you are trying to set your address as unique too? you can have only one unique ID

Comment: I changed the `KEY_ADDRESS` to `"TEXT"` and it didn't work it still crashed the app with the same error